# Check if the JSON string contains a value and give back the SKU

Tags: php, json, strpos

I'm trying to get the SKU when the product_bom contains for example 1.59350, i want to get the parent SKU of a child product in php

I tried this:

```
foreach($json_array as $row){
  if(strpos($row['product_bom'], "1.59350")!== false){
    echo $row['sku'];
  }
}
```

but this returns all SKU's not just one where 1.59350 is found.

JSON data of 1 product with its children:

```
    {
        "sku": "40.0166N",
        "ean": "8715823110967",
        "catalog_index_name-nl_NL": "Argo",
        "product_bom": "{\"meta\":null,\"children\":{\"1.59350\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"8\",\"meta\":null},\"1.60075\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"15\",\"meta\":null},\"2.41930\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"3\",\"meta\":null},\"38.2600\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"3\",\"meta\":null},\"38.2601\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"3\",\"meta\":null},\"38.2602\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"3\",\"meta\":null},\"38.2603\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"3\",\"meta\":null},\"38.2604\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"3\",\"meta\":null},\"38.2605\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"3\",\"meta\":null},\"38.2606\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"3\",\"meta\":null},\"38.2607\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"3\",\"meta\":null},\"38.2608\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"3\",\"meta\":null},\"38.2609\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"3\",\"meta\":null},\"38.2610\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"3\",\"meta\":null},\"38.2611\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"3\",\"meta\":null},\"38.2612\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"3\",\"meta\":null},\"38.2650\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"3\",\"meta\":null},\"38.2651\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"3\",\"meta\":null},\"38.2652\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"3\",\"meta\":null},\"38.2653\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"3\",\"meta\":null},\"38.2654\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"3\",\"meta\":null},\"38.2656\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"3\",\"meta\":null},\"38.2658\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"3\",\"meta\":null},\"38.2659\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"3\",\"meta\":null},\"38.2660\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"3\",\"meta\":null},\"38.2665\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"3\",\"meta\":null},\"38.2666\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"3\",\"meta\":null},\"38.2750\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"2\",\"meta\":null},\"38.2751\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"2\",\"meta\":null},\"38.2752\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"2\",\"meta\":null},\"38.2753\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"2\",\"meta\":null},\"38.2755\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"2\",\"meta\":null},\"38.2756\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"2\",\"meta\":null},\"38.2810\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"3\",\"meta\":null},\"38.2811\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"3\",\"meta\":null},\"38.2812\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"3\",\"meta\":null},\"38.2840\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"3\",\"meta\":null},\"38.2841\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"3\",\"meta\":null},\"38.2842\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"3\",\"meta\":null},\"38.2843\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"3\",\"meta\":null},\"38.2844\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"3\",\"meta\":null},\"40.0166AR\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"1\",\"meta\":null},\"40.0166AZ\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"1\",\"meta\":null},\"40.0166DA\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"1\",\"meta\":null},\"40.0166DMZ\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"1\",\"meta\":null},\"40.0166DT\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"1\",\"meta\":null},\"40.0166DZ\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"1\",\"meta\":null},\"40.0166ER\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"1\",\"meta\":null},\"40.0166EW\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"1\",\"meta\":null},\"40.0166EWB\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"1\",\"meta\":null},\"40.0166EWG\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"1\",\"meta\":null},\"40.0166EWH\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"1\",\"meta\":null},\"40.0166EWOG\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"1\",\"meta\":null},\"40.0166EWR\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"1\",\"meta\":null},\"40.0166EZ\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"1\",\"meta\":null},\"40.0166G1\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"1\",\"meta\":null},\"40.0166G6\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"1\",\"meta\":null},\"40.0166GV\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"1\",\"meta\":null},\"40.0166RF\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"1\",\"meta\":null},\"40.1105\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"1\",\"meta\":null},\"40.1110\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"1\",\"meta\":null},\"40.1120\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"1\",\"meta\":null},\"40.2050\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"3\",\"meta\":null},\"40.2070\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"3\",\"meta\":null},\"40.3139\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"2\",\"meta\":null},\"40.3166\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"1\",\"meta\":null},\"40.35005\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"2\",\"meta\":null},\"40.35007\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"2\",\"meta\":null},\"40.4139A\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"1\",\"meta\":null},\"40.4139GR\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"1\",\"meta\":null},\"40.4139T\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"1\",\"meta\":null},\"40.4139W\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"1\",\"meta\":null},\"40.4166\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"1\",\"meta\":null},\"40.4166A\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"1\",\"meta\":null},\"40.4166EWA\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"1\",\"meta\":null},\"40.4166EWGR\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"1\",\"meta\":null},\"40.4166EWT\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"1\",\"meta\":null},\"40.4166EWW\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"1\",\"meta\":null},\"40.4166G\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"1\",\"meta\":null},\"40.4166W\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"1\",\"meta\":null},\"40.5005\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"2\",\"meta\":null},\"40.5007\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"2\",\"meta\":null},\"40.5008\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"1\",\"meta\":null},\"40.5014\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"1\",\"meta\":null},\"40.5139\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"2\",\"meta\":null},\"40.5166\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"1\",\"meta\":null},\"40.55005\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"2\",\"meta\":null},\"40.55007\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"2\",\"meta\":null},\"40.6139\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"2\",\"meta\":null},\"40.6166\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"1\",\"meta\":null},\"40.65005\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"2\",\"meta\":null},\"40.65007\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"2\",\"meta\":null},\"40.8139\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"2\",\"meta\":null},\"40.8166\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"1\",\"meta\":null},\"40.85005\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"2\",\"meta\":null},\"40.85007\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"2\",\"meta\":null},\"40.9139\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"2\",\"meta\":null},\"40.9166\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"1\",\"meta\":null},\"40.95005\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"2\",\"meta\":null},\"40.95007\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"2\",\"meta\":null},\"40.9970\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"3\",\"meta\":null},\"40.9971\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"3\",\"meta\":null},\"40.9972\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"3\",\"meta\":null},\"40.9973\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"3\",\"meta\":null},\"40.9974\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"3\",\"meta\":null},\"40.9976\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"1\",\"meta\":null},\"40.9980\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"3\",\"meta\":null},\"40.9982\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"3\",\"meta\":null},\"40.9985\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"3\",\"meta\":null},\"40.9986\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"3\",\"meta\":null},\"40.9987\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"3\",\"meta\":null},\"40.9990\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"2\",\"meta\":null},\"42.8055\":{\"group_id\":\"0\",\"group_label\":\"\",\"amount\":\"1\",\"meta\":null}}}"
    },
```

Comment: Change `!== false` to `!== -1`. Strpos return position index or -1 when not found, not boolean

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, unfortunately this still gives all the SKU's back